# OSX - Custom lockscreen incorrect password script

Tags: macos, shell, security, automation

As you probably know, in Mac OS X you can enable a lock screen when waking from sleep, where the user enters their password.  I am looking for a way of running an Automator.app workflow when an incorrect password is entered on the lock screen.